# How can I make npm install package and ignore one (or all) peer dependencies?

Tags: npm, npm-install

I have `vuex@4.0.2` installed. I want to install `vuex-module-decorators@latest`, which has a peerDependency of `vuex 3` (not `>=3`). I have a feeling this will work fine with `vuex 4`. Is there a way for me to tell npm to install this new package, without crashing due to not being able to resolve the peer dependency (since 4 != 3)? Or do I need to just create my own fork of `vuex-module-decorators` with an updated `package.json` that allows `vuex >=3`?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**Fast but potentially unsafe**: Using `--legacy-peer-deps` will usually allow you to install the package without meeting the peer dependency requirements. (This was the default using `npm@6` so I assume you are using `npm@7` or later if you are seeing a problem.) If that doesn't work, `--force` will install without regard to peer dependencies.

**Requires slightly more effort but is more safe/surgical**: Use [npm overrides](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/configuring-npm/package-json#overrides). These were introduced in npm 8.x.

Answer (score 7):

You should use `overrides` with modern versions of npm, since `--legacy-peer-deps` is less safe and could silence other legacy peer dependencies that you may want to fix:

```json
"overrides": {
  "vuex-module-decorators": {
    "vuex": "$vuex",
  }
}
```

Comment: Here `"$vuex"` means "take the version spec of the vuex package from "dependencies" ([_overrides may also be defined as a reference to a spec for a direct dependency by prefixing the name of the package you wish the version to match with a $._](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/configuring-npm/package-json#overrides))

Answer (score 2):

simply try this command

```
npm install --legacy-peer-deps
```

Comment: `--legacy-peer-deps` dangerously ignores peer dependency conflicts, which is why it's no longer the default. Fixing peer dependencies, such as by [using `overrides`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77381233/406249), is safer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want peer dependencies to be automatically installed, add "auto-install-peers=true" to an .npmrc file at the root of your project