# How to install mui 5 in a project with react@16.12 ? I have added peerDependencies script in my package.json file, Still I am getting waring to add it

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, windows-10, package.json, peer-dependencies

> I tried some solutions on stackOverFlow and youTube about peerDependencies. One of them was add a peerDependency in package.json file. Following is my package.json file

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "^17.0.0",
    "@babel/core": "^7.13.0",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.0",
    "typescript": "3.2.0-dev",
    "fsevents": "1.2.13"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.10.5",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.10.5",
    "@mui/material": "^5.11.8",
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.2.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

> After I did npm install, still I am getting this error "WARN @mui/material@5.11.8 requires a peer of react@^17.0.0 || ^18.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself."
> My questions are :

1. How to install peer dependency by yourself means ? I have already added it to package.json. How to add it when there is already react 16.12 running ?
2. I don't want to use mui version 4, Isn't there other ways to club react 16.12 and Material UI 5 ?

Comment: I also tried npm install @mui/material @emotion/react @emotion/styled --legacy-peer-deps, still getting the same warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. How to install peer dependency by yourself means ? I have already added it to package.json. How to add it when there is already react 16.12 running ?

> A peer dependency specifies that our package is compatible with a particular version of an npm package.
> peerDependencies are not automatically installed. You need to manually modify your package.json file in order to add a Peer Dependency.

Source: [Difference between dependencies, devDependencies and peerDependencies](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-dependencies-devdependencies-and-peerdependencies)

> Using `--legacy-peer-deps` will usually allow you to install the package without meeting the peer dependency requirements. If that doesn't work, `--force` will install without regard to peer dependencies.

Source: [How can I make npm install package and ignore one (or all) peer dependencies?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69429293/13346156)

So, You can do:

```
npm install @mui/material@5 --legacy-peer-deps
```

Or

```
npm install @mui/material@5 --force
```

---

> 2. I don't want to use mui version 4, Isn't there other ways to club react 16.12 and Material UI 5 ?

No, You have to upgrade React version, or just ignore the peer dependency requirements warning.

Comment: Thank you @Amr Eraky, you said, 'You need to manually modify your package.json file in order to add a Peer Dependency' , in my above package.json how to add react@17.0.0 as a peerDependency while my project is already running on react@16.12 ?

Comment: `package.json` here means `package.json` of the package (in case you create your own package) https://stackoverflow.com/a/68932368/13346156 . not for your app

Comment: If you open `\node_modules\@mui\material\package.json` for @mui/material v5, you'll find `"peerDependencies": {
"@types/react": "^17.0.0 || ^18.0.0",
},`, This means you can't install it without React 17 or 18, or ignore peer Dependencies